# Why does Document ID link open Property page instead of document?

Tags: document-id

When I click on the DocumentID link for an EMF file, instead of viewing the file, I see the property page for the file.  The link works for all of the TIF images in the same library.  But not for the EMF files.
When I click on the Name link, I can view the file.

Comment: I have similar question, but i search to have the property page instead of downloading file (the opposite of you...).
Have you find something about your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with PDF documents and clicking their DocumentID link.  In that case, it turned out to be that the PDF file type (or in your case, the EMF file type) was not listed in the File Types section of the Search Service Application in SharePoint 2010's Central Administration.

Edit:  I believe we also rebuilt the search index once this new file type was added.

Comment: I had the same issue as Josh and after we 1) added PDF to list of file names, 2) reset search index and 3) rebooted index/search servers, the issue was resolved Thanks!